# How can I modify a Google Chrome extension icon?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

Where are Google Chrome extension resources stored in Mac OS X?

Specifically, I want to edit the adblock extension icon to make it monochrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Extensions

Comment: It's Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions, but I'll give it as a good answer.

Comment: I found my Google Chrome extensions here /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions (Mountain Lion 10.9.4).